# Replace em linha vazia

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma variável com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
10
20 30
40 50 60

70 80 90


100
```

Existem espaços (podendo ter 2 ou mais seguidos) e quebra de linha (também várias na sequência), e quero substituir para ficar desta forma:

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Cada valor em uma linha, sem linhas vazias e sem espaços.

Tentei pelo `conteudo = conteudo.replace(" ", "\n");` mas as linhas vazias ficam.

**Tem como substituir tudo de uma só vez ou limpar essas linhas vazias depois de quebrar todos valores ?**

Comment: Variável do tipo String?

Comment: @Laerte isso, String !

Comment: Ai você quer transformar numa outra string só que formatada da forma que você postou, certo ou quer uma lista com os valores?

Comment: Na mesma String, já "tratada"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pra remover as linhas vazias você pode usar o método **replaceAll** com a expressão regular `\n+`

```
String tratar = "10\n"
        + "20 30\n"
        + "40 50 60\n"
        + "\n"
        + "70 80 90\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n"
        + "100";

String nova = tratar.replace(" ", "\n").replaceAll("\n+", "\n");

System.out.println(nova);
```

Exemplo Funcional: https://ideone.com/AQYWsK

Comment: Não seria mais fácil utilizar apenas uma regex para as duas coisas ? Com por exemplo `\s+|\n+`.

Comment: Sim é possível, só uma correção no regex: `\\s+|\n+`